# XSL to arrange nodes in predefined order in XHTML

Tags: xslt, xhtml

I need to arrange the nodes in XHTML in particular predefined order using XSL, retaining all the other transformation within the nodes. The input file is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
  <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
  </head> 

  <body class="hresume">

    <div id="sec 1">
      <div>
    text 1
    <span class="summary">position 1</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="sec 2">
      <div>
    text 2
    <span class="summary">position 2</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body> 
</html>
```

the XML transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
   version="1.0"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- the identity template -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove summary -->
<xsl:template match="xhtml:span[@class='summary']"/>

<!-- arrange nodes -->
<do-something match="id('sec 2')"/>
<do-something match="id('sec 1')"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected result is just swapping "sec 1" and "sec 2" nodes and removing "summary" positions. What should be used instead of `do-something`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "*[x:div[@id='sec 1'] and x:div[@id='sec 2']]">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>

   <xsl:variable name="vDivs" select="x:div"/>

   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDivs[2]"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="$vDivs[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="x:span[@class='summary']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body class="hresume">
        <div id="sec 1">
            <div>     text 1     
                <span class="summary">position 1</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sec 2">
            <div>     text 2     
                <span class="summary">position 2</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**produces exactly the wanted, correct result**:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
   </head>
   <body class="hresume">
      <div id="sec 2">
         <div>     text 2     
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="sec 1">
         <div>     text 1     
        </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Do note**:

1. The wanted special effect is achieved by having two separate `<xsl:apply-templates>` instructions specified in the desired order.
2. The wanted switching of places between the two `div` elements is achieved even if the second one were preceding the first one -- in the result always the one that was second (of the two) in document order is now first (of the two) in document order.

Comment: I've provided a solution based on `xsl:key`. I'd like to know what you think about as I'm just trying to improve my skills @SO. Thanks

Comment: thanks! it works perfectly and can be extended easily for more then two sections. there is a bug in `match` though: it takes all the `div` at this level, I've noticed this when added one more `<div id="sec 3">` node to the test case.

Comment: @zeliboba: You are welcome. I don't consider this a bug, because it works on the provided XML document, and there isn't any additional information about your plans for extending this. You may elaborate this in a new question and I'd be happy to provide answers.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `xsl:key` and switches the divs, any order they are provided:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="sec" match="x:body/x:div[@id]" use="@id"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:div[@id='sec 1']">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">         
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sec','sec 2')/*|key('sec','sec 2')/@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:div[@id='sec 2']">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('sec','sec 1')/*|key('sec','sec 1')/@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:div[@id='sec 2']/*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:div[@id='sec 1']/*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:span[@class='summary']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your solution will strip all attributes from the `body` element. Is this intended? If not, you should probably add `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` inside `<xsl:copy>`.

Comment: @markusk - you are true, that's not intended, just a miscode :). Thanks, now is correct. Great comment!

Comment: This transformation doesn't do anything except a complete identity te=ransform -- try it (and get into the habit of always trying your proposed solutions before posting them).

Comment: @empo: Why are you insisting that your code produces anything other than complete identity? I tried it before deciding that this code really should be downvoted. You either haven't run your transformation on the XML document provided by the OP and seen what it produces, or your XSLT processor is hopelessly buggy and incompliant (which is less likely). Let me help a bit with this hint: have you heard about the problem of selecting elements that are in a default namespace? Your match patterns that contain unprefixed names do not match any node in the document, this is why identity is the result.

Comment: @empo: Your new transformation also produces just a copy of the source XML document as the first solution does. Due to the same reasons. So, both "solutions" are wrong, untested and have misleading claims attached to them.

Comment: @empo: Just run your transformation and see that it (both of them) do nothing -- they just copy the source XML document unchanged. I have run your transformations with 9 different XSLT processors -- with the same result. Either correct your answer, or delete it, please.

Comment: @Dimitre: ok blame upon me. I've just tried with *Saxon* and it happens that you are true. But, why with this online processor both xsl are working fine? That's very strange. [Try it](http://xslttest.appspot.com/).

Comment: @empo: As I said, don't use incompliant XSLT "processors", use real ones. It would also be appropriate if you could delete all your previous comments and leave just the last one. And of course, correct your answer.

Comment: @Dimitre: ok I've added now a solution with `xsl:key` working with _Saxon_. I had hard time for this, but it seems correct now (hopefully). Thanks for your feedback, and sorry for having insisted in my point while I was using incompliant XSLT processor.

Comment: @empo: Great step forward. The new solution seems correct (for the first time) because you now deal with the default namespace problem. Do note that using keys makes a transformation faster only if the `key()` function is used more than once with the same arguments.

Comment: the solution looks bulky if you have more then two sections

Comment: This is just an example, based on your assumptions: two sections to switch. If you have more sections, I would use it to create a template function and use `call-template`.